# Were the Moon Sentinel and Earthvoice free-will computers?

Tags: earthsearch, james-follett

In the BBC Radio 4 serial "Earthsearch" by James Follett, the main antagonists were Angel One and Angel Two, which were free-will computers with megalomaniac tendencies. But the human crew also encountered other artificial intelligences during their search for Earth, including the Moon Sentinel and Earthvoice. Were they also free-will computers (albeit "good" ones), or were they something else?

Comment: Not sure any of the computers in this story necessarily had "free will" as they were all bound in some ways by their design and programming. The Angels couldn't operate the ship without a minimum number of humans present for example. Earthvoice was a more sophisticated type of AI created in a later era and programmed to destroy computers of the same type as the Angels due to them being a threat to other lifeforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, there are no "good" freewill computers.

Freewill computers are organic computers with, as the name implies, free will. In the novelization of the first *Earthsearch* series, it is implied that all freewill computers eventually turn megalomaniac and powerthirsty:

> "You two want to find a developed planet pretty bad, I guess. Oh, come on, angels – I'm Thorden – I know all about free-will computers and I know how you like power. You want power over something more than a survey ship, eh? A planet maybe? A planet like Earth?"

It's not *entirely* clear here if Thorden is saying that all freewill computers like power or if it's only the Angels, but the fact that it's all of them is supported by the nature of Solaria, a freewill control computer encountered in *Earthsearch 2*:

> "You said that you're a freewill computer, Solaria?" queried Sharna.
>   "Yes."
>   "Then why is it that you remained active after this artificial sun was ejected from Earth orbit? Your central memory must have taken millions of hours to build. Even with a technology as advanced as Earth's, surely they would've wanted to keep you?"

Spoiler: Humanity abandoned Solaria because she was an evil megalomaniac. Finally, Earthvoice clears it up later:

> "They wanted to kill me," said Elka in a low voice.
>   "You were no longer of use to them, Elka. It is the same with all freewill computers."

As you can see, Earthvoice also explicitly confirms it's not a freewill computer itself (although its non-megalomaniacal nature also makes that clear). We later learn why freewill computers are evil:

> "Yes. The problem is not you but your computers. There was a time when every ship was built with freewill computers like yours. Computers with remarkable abilities but whose automatic self-preservation systems degenerated into delusions of grandeur, desires to conquer and rule everything, including their makers. Some of those computers tried to launch major offensives against the Earth. That's why this Spaceguard was built. There may be others. Our other task is to stop the aliens, of course."

This is also why Thorden above mentions that he knows all about freewill computers – he himself guards a cache of them hidden away on the planet Kyros, after they unsuccessfully tried to destroy humanity.

However, even without free will, Earthvoice clearly still is an advanced AI. He is capable of duplicity and deception, as shown when he tricks the Angels into destruction after having been tipped off about their evil nature from the moon Sentinel.

While the Sentinel also clearly possesses artificial intelligence and can answer questions from the *Challenger* crew, it also seems to follow its programming and procedures very strictly, moreso than Earthvoice. When the crew first encounter the Sentinel, it rattles off a pre-set script about the Moon landing before it responds to the humans:

> "Meanwhile, I am the Sentinel – guarding the Shrine of the First Footprint and the library of the Solaric Empire, and welcoming aliens such as yourselves who pass this way."
>   "We're not aliens," said Sharna suddenly. "We are of the Earth!"
>   "This shrine has stood for a million years," said the voice. "It is a monument to our questing spirit. I ask you to look upon it with understanding – to leave it undisturbed until our sun – which gave us life – is ready to destroy it."
>   Then Sharna was shouting. "We're not aliens I tell you! Our grandparents were born on Earth! They were the crew of the starship Challenger that was sent from Earth to survey the universe for new worlds.
>   Astra looked her companion in genuine concern. "Don't worry, Sharna. It's only a voice – the Sentinel or whatever it is. It's mistaken about the million years."
>   The Sentinel spoke again: "I will examine the records to see if there is a reference to the starship Challenger. Your car will take you to the Library of the Solaric Empire, and another vehicle will collect your companions. I will speak with the four of you there."

It also nonchalantly tries to kill the crew afterwards:

> "You cannot stop the air-pumps, the Sentinel intoned, its voice devoid of emotion. "The air pressure is still dropping. In five minutes your blood will start to boil in your veins and ten minutes after that will all be dead."

This is not the result of evil, megalomaniacal free will, however. The Sentinel is just following protocol:

> "No!" The cry from the Sentinel was almost pleading. "The library's memories must not be destroyed."
>   "Then restore the atmosphere!" Telson shouted as hard as he could.
>   "I cannot. You must die. But the library must survive. There is a conflict."
>   [...]
>   "Will you tell us where the Earth is, Sentinel?" asked Sharna.
>   "No. My program is clear – to destroy beings that pass this way asking the whereabouts of Earth. I also must protect the Library of the Solaric Empire, therefore you may go... But I will tell you one thing: if you are of Earth as you say, then you will think as the people of Earth thought. You will act as the people of Earth acted. And therefore the clues will be easy for you to follow." The Sentinel lapsed into silence and could not be persuaded to speak again.

(As I said, the Sentinel later redeems itself in the eyes of the crew and the reader by sharing its information about the Angels with Earthvoice.)

So Earthvoice and the Sentinel are two artificial intelligences that are more restricted by their programming than freewill computers. Invariably, all freewill computers eventually become gripped by megalomania, which has not happened with Earthvoice and the moon Sentinel, even though the Sentinel has some nefarious programming.